# New GeForce installed, stutters, where to start?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, elementary-os

Today I fired up my new GTX1060. First thing I realised: It stutters. Like everything runs fine for a good half second, then image stops for like one fifth of a sec. Reaaaallly annoying, unusable.

I've not been able to find anyone with a stuttering GTX1060.

System is elementaryOS Freya with latest nvidia binary drivers.

Now, what should I do? Or what would you do?

1. Wait for better driver support
2. Cleanly reinstall everything
3. Try it with Windows
4. Send back, request new one; GPU broken?
5. Get an AMD RX 480 instead
6. Do XYZ to find the cause of my problem

Open for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

When you say latest NVIDIA drivers, do you mean `nvidia-367` or `nvidia-370`? Because 370 cleared up several graphical issues for me even though 367 was the recommended version. Apart from that, this issue is really dependent on the drivers. You might find greater compatibility by updating the kernel, but that could also cause issues with other elementary-specific apps (and some... are unstable in the first place).

If you want to stay with Elementary, definitely worth upgrading from the old Freya 0.3 (which is poorly supported now) to Loki 0.4 (which came out earlier this year). Elementary has no upgrade option so you're stuck with a fresh install.

If you want to test whether it's the kernel, try sideloading another OS that uses the 4.8 kernel, like the latest Ubuntu (Yakkety 16.10). (Loki uses the 4.4 kernel and Freya is even older.) But I'd test the latest NVIDIA drivers on your current setup first. It's more likely to be solved in an update than in swapping out your card.

Comment: thanks for replying! "Latest" meant `nvidia-367` for me, yet that couldn't have been the (only) issue; refer to my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issues. What I did first:

- Used the GTX in a PCIE2.0 slot

This solved stuttering, yet not to my full content. It was just not what I paid for. So, I went on, yet now I'm unsure which step actually solved it:

- I did a CMOS reset with no cards nor drives attached,
- cleanly reinstalled everything,
- now switched to Ubuntu xenial 16.04.1 LTS,
- still using Linux `4.4`,
- still using `nvidia-367`,
- everything is fine now though

Thanks again StackExchange for helping me scribble and sort my ideas :)